# How to switch execution to a new script in Python?

Tags: python, exec, execute

Is it possible to have one script call another and then exit (don't know if I'm putting this right), leaving the other script running? Specifically I want an update script to download `installer.py` and then run it. Since `installer.py` overwrites the update script I can't just do a `subprocess.call()` since it will fail at the 'delete old install' stage.

Is this possible or must I instead leave the updater script alone, replace everything else, put the new one in a temporary directory and then replace it next time the program is run? Is this considered a better approach?

Thank you very much and sorry if this is blindingly obvious.

Comment: Note that once a Python module has been imported, you no longer need the source file around. So it is possible to have the update script run the installer as a subprocess, and as long as the update script doesn't need to reload its old version, it should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

One of the [`os.exec*` family](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.execl) of functions should do what you want.

Comment: Thankyou very much - that looks like just thing. I shall give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're downloading another Python script, you could try using `exec` to run it. In 2.x there is a helper function `execfile` for this sort of thing (which wraps the use of the `exec` keyword; in 3.x you must read the file and pass the resulting string to `exec` (which is now a function, if I'm reading correctly).

<sub>**You must always be 110% sure you trust the content in cases like this!** It seems that this isn't an issue for you, though.</sub>

Comment: Python's exec is sort of like eval in other languages, and not at all like libc exec. In particular, it doesn't replace the current program.